# Select one of polygons that intersect from a single table

Tags: postgis

I have imported points objects from dxf/dwg (exported from Inkscape) in QGis and although the stroke was set on 0, I get for each point 3 shapes made of lines. When I polygonize them with Postgis I get of course 3 shapes as well for each point : 1 "big" polygon and 2 others that are only borders around it.
[image]

So I would like to select for each case only 1 polygon and delete the others. I have thinked of using `st_centroid` and keep only 1 of 3 by deleting duplicate geometries but the centroids don't overlap since the polygons don't have exactly the same extent. How could I achieve this ?

Comment: Do they share a common identifier?

Comment: Unfortunately, no...

Comment: I finally selected the good polygons by using `st_area` and picking the largest. But it would be very useful to have a "universal method" only based on intersecting shapes.

Comment: What about to select polygons with no holes? https://postgis.net/docs/ST_NumInteriorRings.html